# How to access Database from Asp.netcore By using Entityfrmework

Tags: asp.net-core

Here i setup some Db connection from Anguar2 to database but when i try to hit database I'm Getting error as `Additional information: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the`

This is my database connection

```
{
  "connectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=MD;Database=Md;userid=sa;password=123;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
```

**startUp.cs**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           services.AddDbContext<StudentContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

**DbContext.cs**

```
 public class StudentContext:DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext(DbContextOptions<StudentContext> options) : base(options) {  }
        public StudentContext() { }

         public DbSet<StudentMaster> StudentMaster { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the correct variable in the appsettings.json (or whatever the name of your file)

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);




        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

    }
```

then make sure you get the [intended variable](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/) (**connectionStrings:DefaultConnection** for your case)

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           services.AddDbContext<StudentContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionStrings:DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

you can also set the connection string on the data context directly by overriding the `OnConfiguring` like this

```
public class StudentContext : DbContext
    {




    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("_connectionString_", _options => _options.EnableRetryOnFailure());

    }
```

}

Comment: appsetting.json i mentioned as  i write in this file could u plz conform me this is r8 or wrong config